# jQuery AJAX Call Triggers Error Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this ajax call in my code, but it triggers the error function everytime. Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/GSTArticles/GoogleMaps/Landmarks.xml',
    datatype: 'xml',
    success: function(xml){
        console.log(xml);
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert("ERROR!");
    }
});
```

To my understanding, the syntax looks correct. Can someone help me to see why this triggers an error, rather than placing the xml into my console? Thanks.

I also see this in the console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/GSTArticles/GoogleMaps/Landmarks.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: well it triggers the error function, and I see this in the console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/GSTArticles/GoogleMaps/Landmarks.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: you must try using an error handler : 
`error : function(fai,lu,re) { alert( fai +" "+lu +" "+re)}`

Comment: I see that youre making a cross-domain call. Its not possible to do this without `jsonp`

Comment: i already have an error handler though. 
**function(err){alert(ERROR!);}**

Comment: @passionateCoder: can you explain that please? jsonp? im trying to get an xml though?

Comment: https://www.bionicspirit.com/blog/2011/03/24/cross-domain-requests.html

Comment: @chaitanya.varanasi this handler will not tell u what error ur facing :) its highly essential that u see the error because it'll help u debug ur code :)

Comment: Try changing your error function alert to alert("error: "+err.responseText);  so that you can see the exact error that is happening.

Comment: @Phil: I got this exactly: "error: ". No response text.

Comment: @passionateCoder: Thanks! I am looking at the document now. Ill write something up and post if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jsonp to do a cross domain request with ajax - which means you can't request XML using jQuery's ajax method.  Here are other related questions.

[cross domain issue with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8847893/1385672)

[How to Parse XML Cross-domain in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10068963/1385672)

You can use [Yahoo API library (YQL)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/index.html) to to get the xml though

Source from http://www.cypressnorth.com/blog/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-xml-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/

```
// Accepts a url and a callback function to run.
function requestCrossDomain(site, callback) {

    // If no url was passed, exit.
    if (!site) {
        alert('No site was passed.');
        return false;
    } 
    // Take the provided url, and add it to a YQL query. Make sure you encode it!
    var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';

    // Request that YSQL string, and run a callback function.
    // Pass a defined function to prevent cache-busting.
    $.getJSON(yql, cbFunc);

    function cbFunc(data) {
        // If we have something to work with...
        if (data.results[0]) {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(data);
            }
        }
        // Else, Maybe we requested a site that doesn't exist, and nothing returned.
        else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
    }
}
function xmlSuccess(data){
    console.log(data.results[0]);
}
requestCrossDomain('https://s3.amazonaws.com/GSTArticles/GoogleMaps/Landmarks.xml',xmlSuccess);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nf79p/)